# Map function to write on global spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of strings. Each line corresponding to various logs.

I have multiple regex in one single function that match/case the lines of the RDD to apply the adapted regex.

I want to map this unique function on my RDD, so it can process every lines fastly, and store each line processed in an other global rdd.

Problem is, as I want this task to be parallelized, my global RDD must be accessible concurrently to add every processed lines.

I was wondering if there was an other way to do this or anything ! I'm looking to improve my spark skills.

For example, this is what I wanna do :

I have a txt like :

> ERROR : Hahhaha param_error=8 param_err2=https
>
> WARNING : HUHUHUHUH param_warn=tchu param_warn2=wifi

My regex function will match the lines containing "ERROR" with an array for example `Array("Error","8","https")`

And another regex function will match the lines containing "WARNING" with an array for example `Array("Warning","tchu","wifi")`

At the end, I wanna obtain a `RDD[Array[String]]` for every line processed.

How do I keep it parallelized with Spark ?

Comment: "I have multiple regex in one single function that match/case the lines of the RDD to apply the adapted regex" - can you edit your post to include the _signature_ of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's important to understand that there's nothing like a "global RDD" in Spark, nor is there a reason you'd need something like that. When using Spark, you should think in terms of *transforming* one RDD into another, and not in terms of *updating* RDDs (which is impossible - RDDs are *immutable*). Each such *transformation* will be executed distributedly (in parallel) by Spark.

In this case, if I understand your requirement correctly, you'd want to `map` each record into one of the following results:

- an `Array[String]` where the first item is `"ERROR"`, or:
- an `Array[String]` where the first item is `"WARNING"`, or:
- if no pattern matched the record, *remove* it

To do that, you can use the `map(f)` and `collect(f)` methods of `RDD`:

```
// Sample data:
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "ERROR : Hahhaha param_error=8 param_err2=https",
  "WARNING : HUHUHUHUH param_warn=tchu param_warn2=wifi",
  "Garbage - not matching anything"
))

// First we can split in " : " to easily identify ERROR vs. WARNING 
val splitPrefix = rdd.map(line => line.split(" : "))

// Implement these parsing functions as you see fit; 
// The input would be the part following the " : ", 
// and the output should be a list of the values (not including the ERROR / WARNING) 
def parseError(v: String): List[String] = ??? // example input: "Hahhaha param_error=8 param_err2=https"
def parseWarning(v: String): List[String] = ??? // example input: "HUHUHUHUH param_warn=tchu param_warn2=wifi"

// Now we can use these functions in a pattern-matching function passed to RDD.collect,
// which will transform each value that matches one of the cases, and will filter out 
// values that don't match anything
val result: RDD[List[String]] = splitPrefix.collect {
  case Array(l @ "ERROR", v) => l :: parseError(v)
  case Array(l @ "WARNING", v) => l :: parseWarning(v)
  // NOT adding a default case, so records that didn't match will be removed
}    

// If you really want Array[String] and not List[String]:    
val arraysRdd: RDD[Array[String]] = result.map(_.toArray)
```

Comment: Oh yes damn, that's exactly what I wanted ! Thanks a lot, I didn't know we could use the collect function like this. Progressing in Spark every day, thanks man ! :p